# How to force start Control M jobs using Unix Script

Tags: linux, unix, control-m, service-control-manager

I am able to Force Start jobs in Autosys using shell script but for Control M I am not finding any shell script command to Force start jobs.

Any Command we have to force start Control Job?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
ctmcreate
```

It create the job on the fly

If you have access to the Control-M API you can do:

```
ctm run job::runNow "server-test:000fp"
```

Also, you can set your Job for "Confirmation" and confirm it when you want using this command:

```
ctmpsm -UPDATEAJF <orderid> <HOLD|FREE|DELETE|UNDELETE|RERUN|CONFIRM|SETTOOK|STATISTICS|CONDADDIN <cond> <date> <AND|OR>|CONDADDOUT <cond> <date> <+|->|CONDDELIN <cond>|CONDDELOUT <cond>
```